# Powershell to remove-adgroupmembers listed in a text file where the group for them to be removed from is a wildcard

Tags: powershell, active-directory, activedirectorymembership

I'm looking for a way to remove AD computers that are listed in a text file from any
AD groups they might be in, within the same OU. For example, the text file contains: 
Computer1$
Computer2$
Computer3$

The groups those three computers might appear in are: 
Group1
Group2
Group3

I found this on StackOverflow from 2016 from the title "PowerShell - Remove-ADGroupMember - Locking my admin account" and edited for me: 
Get-ADGroup -filter 'name -like "Group*"' | Remove-ADGroupMember -Members "Computer3$" 
This works fine to remove "Computer3$! But when I try to replace "Computer3$" with my variable in a Foreach, it breaks. Here's my code:

```
$Comps = Get-Content "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Complist.txt"
foreach ($comp in $comps) {
Get-ADGroup -filter 'name -like "Group*"' | Remove-ADGroupMember -Members "$Comps"
}
```

and errors with:

```
Remove-ADGroupMember : Cannot find an object with identity: 'Computer1$
Computer2$ Computer3$' under: 'DC=Domain,DC=local'.
At line:3 char:53
+ ... name -like "Group*"' | Remove-ADGroupMember -Members "$Comps"
+                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Computer1...mputer3$:ADP 
   rincipal) [Remove-ADGroupMember], ADIdentityNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SetADGroupMember.ValidateMembersParameter,Microsoft.Ac 
   tiveDirectory.Management.Commands.RemoveADGroupMember
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$Comps = Get-Content "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Complist.txt"
foreach ($comp in $comps) {
Get-ADGroup -filter 'name -like "Group*"' | Remove-ADGroupMember -Members "$comp"
}
```

You were referencing `$comps` (the group of objects) instead of `$comp` (the object) inside your loop.

```
Import-Module -Name ActiveDirectory
$listofcomputers = Get-Content -Path "$env:HOMEDRIVE\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Complist.txt"

foreach ($computer in $listofcomputers) {
    Get-ADGroup -Filter 'name -like "Group*"' | Remove-ADGroupMember -Members ('{0}' -f $computer)
}
```

Better variable naming would help here.

Comment: "You were referencing $comps (the group of objects) instead of $comp (the object) inside your loop." Well, that's embarrassing. Many thanks and also for the included suggestions. Would you mind elaborating on what the addition of "('{0}' -f $computer)" does? Thanks again!

Comment: Just a fancy (or easier for me) way of [formatting strings in powershell](https://adamtheautomator.com/powershell-string-format/)